# Clickonce update without overwriting config

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

I want deploy many client (WPF) with Clickonce, i would not overwriting configuration file when i update client. It is possible ?

not include the file for update ? or make a differential update ?
In fact I do not want to crush the connectionString in the updated with ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1):

Use Settings.settings file (go to project properties -> settings) instead of App.config.
For ClickOnce Settings.settings will be stored in "%InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings" and won't be overwritten with every new update.

More about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx